# Improving Performance of a leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, r-markdown, flexdashboard, leaflet.markercluster

I am trying to plot a map using Leaflet on Flexdashboard, output : html. I have a 50,000 data points i needed to plot. i tried using `addCircleMarker(lng,lat)` and it works in Base R but when the output is generated in an HTML file the performance of the map is so slow. I also tried using `leafletOptions(preferCanvas = TRUE)`but the performance is still very slow.

I also tried using a different `library(leaflet.glify)` to improve performance as `leaflet.glify`can handle large dataset and used `addGlifyPoints(data, color = cbind(0, 0, 0.1), group = "All cases")` to plot the map. but i could not run it in an HTML output. It provided me with below error.

```
pandoc: Could not determine mime type for `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/leaflet.glify/htmlwidgets/Leaflet.glify/src/shader/fragment/dot.glsl'
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Text/Pandoc/SelfContained.hs:156:35 in pandoc-1.19.2.1-JIeRA5EnQv74mk86CvVbbp:Text.Pandoc.SelfContained
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
Execution halted
```

Any help please.

Comment: what version of pandoc do you have installed? I've found v2.1 solved this type of error.

Comment: im using 2.1 but nothing changed for me. Still have issue with performance when plotting 50,000 data points.  `get_pandoc_version()`` [1] 2.1`

Comment: Below is the library and its version
 `[1] googleway_2.7.1       bindrcpp_0.2.2        sf_0.7-2              readxl_1.1.0         
 [5] colourvalues_0.2.1    leaflet.glify_0.1.1   forcats_0.3.0         stringr_1.3.1        
 [9] purrr_0.2.5           readr_1.1.1           tidyr_0.8.2           tibble_1.4.2         
[13] ggplot2_3.1.0         tidyverse_1.2.1       dplyr_0.7.7           htmltools_0.3.6      
[17] htmlwidgets_1.3       rgeos_0.4-2           rgdal_1.3-6           sp_1.3-1             
[21] leaflet_2.0.2         flexdashboard_0.5.1.1 pandocfilters_0.1-1`

Comment: and my Rmarkdown version is `rmarkdown_1.10` @SymbolixAU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `leaflet.glify` you need to set `self_contained: false` in your yaml header:

````
---
title: "testing gl"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: fill
    self_contained: false
---

### Chart 1

```{r}
library(mapview)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.glify)
library(sf)

n = 1e5

df1 = data.frame(id = 1:n,
                 x = rnorm(n, 10, 3),
                 y = rnorm(n, 49, 1.8))

pts = st_as_sf(df1, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)

options(viewer = NULL) # view in browser

system.time({
  m = leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles(provider = providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter) %>%
    addGlifyPoints(data = pts, group = "pts") %>%
    addMouseCoordinates() %>%
    setView(lng = 10.5, lat = 49.5, zoom = 6) %>% 
    addLayersControl(overlayGroups = "pts")
})

m
```

### Chart 2

```{r}
plot(cars)
```
````

Comment: Hi @TimSalabim i tried using `self_contained : false` and it renders the `addGlifyPoints` . and works perfectly when I open the HTML output within the `R.project` working directory, but the images are no longer displayed when I send the file to someone. Not sure what is going on there? does anyone have this issue ?

Comment: If your map is called `map.html` there should also be a folder called `map_files` where all necessary code is stored (that's what selfcontained false means). You will need to send both the html and the folder to get the map displayed